# CALayer and Showing Part of its Contents

Tags: ios, calayer

Is there a way to only display part of a CALayer's contents?  I have tried using contentRect; however, I am not quite sure if it works as I need it.  Let's say I have a image and I only need to show parts of the image as the user drags their finger across it.  Is contentRect the way to go?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `bounds` property

```
imageView.layer.bounds = CGRectMake(20, 20, 200, 200);
```